# How to show a form field based on another form value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know how to have a form setup so if an option is selected, a text input is shown.

I am after the text input to only show if option "y" is selected.

I suspect this is more of a jquery/js thing but I'm trying to keep as much of it server side as possible.

```
<label for="resetpw">Reset Password</label>
    <select name="resetpw">
        <option value"n">No</option>
        <option value="y">Yes</option>
            <? if($_POST['resetpw']=='y'){?><p><label for="password">Reset Password</label><input type="password" name="password"></p> <? };?>
    </select>
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with databases and few to do with php unless you use a solution that includes page reloading. It is a javascript task and you can find plenty of examples of this

Comment: This should be done on the client side using javascrpit. You cannot execute php on the client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real reason for doing client-side things on server-side.

E.g. Anything that doesn't involve processing and is not sensitive data.

The fact that you're only enabling and disabling the visibility of the input, you can simply use `jQuery` like I did in the code below.

---

**Code Snippet**

```js
    $("#resetpw_select").on("change", function() {
      if ($(this).val() == "y") {
        $("#input_").append("<input type='password' name='password'>");
      } else {
        $("#input_ input").remove();
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="resetpw">Reset Password</label>

<select name="resetpw" id="resetpw_select">
  <option value="n">No</option>
  <option value="y">Yes</option>
</select>

<p id="input_"></p>
```